# Efficiently filling torch.Tensor at equal index positions

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a 6 dimensional all-zero pytorch tensor `lrel_w` that I want to fill with 1s at positions where the indices of the first three dimensions and the indices of the last three dimensions match. I'm currently solving this trivially using 3 nested for loops:

```
lrel_w = torch.zeros(
  input_size[0], input_size[1], input_size[2],
  input_size[0], input_size[1], input_size[2]
)
for c in range(input_size[0]):
  for x in range(input_size[1]):
    for y in range(input_size[2]):
      lrel_w[c,x,y,c,x,y] = 1
```

I'm sure there must be a more efficient way of doing this, however I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Without knowing why you want to construct this, it is difficult to find a more efficient alternative, and for how many data points (e.g., what is input size typically?)

Comment: It's a weight matrix that stores a set of weights for each pixel of an MNIST image. Each weight set is respective to a set of neurons in a convolutional layer. So a typical shape of `lrel_w` is for example `[1,28,28,16,28,28]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one.

```py
import torch
c, m, n = input_size[0], input_size[1], input_size[2]

t = torch.zeros(c, m, n, c, m, n)
i, j, k = torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(c), torch.arange(m), torch.arange(n))
i = i.flatten()
j = j.flatten()
k = k.flatten()

t[i, j, k, i, j, k] = 1
```

Here is how [meshgrid](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.meshgrid.html) works in case you need reference.

Comment: This is twice according to my timings. Nice!

Comment: Thanks, this works great! For the typical tensor shapes of my problem (`[1,28,28,16,28,28]`), this provides roughly a 150x speed-up  on my machine, compared to the 3 nested for loops.