# How to fill pytorch tensor with a non-scalar value?

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, pytorch, tensor

How do I fill a pytorch tensor with a non-scalar value?

For example, let's say I want to fill a pytorch tensor `X` of shape `(n_samples, n_classes)` with a 1D pytorch vector `a` of shape `(n_classes,)`. Ideally, I'd like to be able to write :

```
X = torch.full((n_samples, n_classes), a)
```

where the vector `a` is the `fill_value` in `torch.full`. However `torch.full` only accepts a scalar as the `fill_value` ([Source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.full.html)). So this code won't work.

I have two questions:

1. If I can't use `torch.full`, what is a fast way to fill `X` with `n_sample` copies of `a`?
2. Why does `torch.full` only accept scalar fill values? Is there a good reason for why the `torch.full` implementation cannot accept tensor fill values?

Regarding question 1., I am thinking about simply writing:

```
X = torch.ones((n_samples, n_classes)) * a
```

However, is there a faster/more efficient way to do this?

For reference, I've already checked out the following stack overflow posts

- [In pytorch, how to fill a tensor with another tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403627/in-pytorch-how-to-fill-a-tensor-with-another-tensor)
- [Fill tensor with another tensor where mask is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688647/fill-tensor-with-another-tensor-where-mask-is-true)
- [Efficiently filling torch.Tensor at equal index positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145069/efficiently-filling-torch-tensor-at-equal-index-positions)
- [Add blocks of values to a tensor at specific locations in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65571114/add-blocks-of-values-to-a-tensor-at-specific-locations-in-pytorch)

but none of these directly answer my question.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `X = a.expand(n_samples, -1).clone()` ?

Comment: +1 for a solution using `.expand()` which provides a tensor view rather than a new tensor with copied data, if your problem is of significant size `expand` will be much more memory-efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [torch.tile](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tile.html) is what you want. The code would be

```
X = torch.tile(a, (n_samples, 1))
```

Example

```
>>> a = torch.arange(5)
>>> a
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> n_samples = 3
>>> X = torch.tile(a, (n_samples, 1))
>>> X
tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```